# How can I convert ASCII code to characters in Verilog language

Tags: ascii, verilog, modelsim

I've been looking into this but searching seems to lead to nothing.
It might be too simple to be described, but here I am, scratching my head...
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Verilog knows about "strings".

A single ASCII character requires 8 bits. Thus to store 8 characters you need 64 bits:

```
wire [63:0] string8;

assign string8 = "12345678";
```

There are some gotchas:

- There is no End-Of-String character (like the C null-character)
- The most RHS character is in bits 7:0.
  Thus string8[7:0] will hold 8h'38. ("8").
- To walk through a string you have to use e.g.: `string[ index +: 8];`
- As with all Verilog vector assignments: unused bits are set to zero thus
  `assign string8 = "ABCD"; // MS bit63:32 are zero`
- You can **not** use two dimensional arrays:
  `wire [7:0] string5 [0:4]; assign string5 = "Wrong";`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably mislead by a misconception about characters. There are no such thing as a character in hardware. There are only sets of bits or codes. The only thing which converts binary codes to characters is your terminal. It interprets codes in a certain way and forming letters for you to se. So, all the `printfs` in 'c' and `$display` in verilog only send the codes to the terminal (or to a file).

The thing which converts characters to the codes is your keyboard, which you also use to type in the program. The compiler then interprets your program. Verilog (as well as the 'c') compiler represents strings in double quotes (which you typed in) as a set of bytes directly. Verilog, as well as 'c' use ascii-8 encoding for such character strings, meaning that the code for 'a' is decimal 97 and 'b' is 98, ....   Every character is 8-bit wide and the quoted string forms a concatenation of bytes of ascii codes.

So, answering you question, you can convert an ascii codes to characters by sending them to the terminal via $display (or other) function, using the %s modifier.

So, an example:

```
module A;
    reg[8*5-1:0] hello; 
    reg[8*3 - 1: 0] bye;
    initial begin
       hello = "hello"; // 5 bytes of characters
       bye = {8'd98, 8'd121, 8'd101}; // 3 bytes 'b' 'y' 'e'
       $display("hello=%s bye=%s", hello, bye);
    end
endmodule
```